# add class to body based on browsed page with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

i'm working on my own php project ad learning php and i was trying to get the body to add class by the page name like:

```
<body class='homepage'><!-- for index.php -->
<body class='single-post'><!-- for posts.php -->
```

my code:

```
<?php include "header.php";?>
<?php include "post.php";?>
<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

UPDATE

i tried and make it work myself by

```
<?php 
    $classone = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(strpos($classone, 'index') != false){
        echo "<body class='homepage'>";
    }else{
        echo "<body>";
    }
?>
```

but i'm hoping if there's any function on php can do the work or a better way to do it

Comment: This is a very basic PHP task; have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i updated the question please take a look at it :))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kind of a vague question, but I think I understand what is being asked.
The page name has be extracted from the request and ran through a lookup table to get the desired class name for the body.

The page file names can be found in the $_SERVER array using the PHP_SELF index, so with the `pathinfo` function, the name can be easily extracted.

```
$page_name = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Next, a lookup table is required, to translate the `$page_name` into a css class name.  I strongly discourage this practice as it can lead to confusion.  Best to keep the class and page names consistent with each other for better maintainability and a less brittle product.

If you have new PHP (>=5.4)(which you should be using a newer version):

```
$class_lookup_table = [
  'index' => 'homepage',
  'posts' => 'single-post'
];
```

If you have old PHP (<5.4)

```
$class_lookup_table = array(
  'index' => 'homepage',
  'posts' => 'single-post'
);
```

Now you can reference the class name in the HTML

```
<body class="<?php $class_lookup_table[$page_name] ?>">
```

Comment: thanks! that worked 
but i have a small problem cause i have make an.htaccess file to rewrite posts url from post?id=1 tp post/1 and linked the .htaccess with a php file named router.php the name of the post page became router.php

`<?php
$segments=explode('/',trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'),3);
switch($segments[1]){
    case 'post':
        $_REQUEST['id']=(string)$segments[2];
        $_GET['id']=(string)$segments[2];
        //$slug=$segments[3];
        require_once('post.php');
        break;
}
?>`

Comment: Found this article on PHP pretty URL rewrites. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049